# Why is my teacher telling me, my return statements are wrong when my code works perfectly

Tags: java, computer-science

I'm making a simple Black Jack game and I finished and thought I asked my teacher what he thought because the code works, but he said that my return statements are incorrect. I understand they are in a void but I'm not trying to return anything I'm just trying to back to the main method(which is the main menu) when some wins or loses. Why is this incorrect or how do I tell him this is correct.

I've tried putting my main method in my other methods but that didn't work, other than that I am fairly new to java (and coding in general) and need some help.

```````
       {
        System.out.println("\n READY AND START");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("what is the dealer called?");
        String cname = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How much money are you willing to bet?");
        int wager = input.nextInt();
        int playerTotal, computerTotal, playerRunning, computerRunning;
        playerTotal = 0;
        computerTotal = 0;
        Random cards = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            playerRunning = 2 + cards.nextInt(10);
            playerTotal += playerRunning;
            System.out.println(name + " your starting card is " + playerRunning);
        }
        System.out.println(name + " your starting hand total is " + playerTotal);
        if (playerTotal == 21) {
            System.out.println("i guess the house doesnt always win" + name + " you got a blackjack here is your money  $" + (wager * 1.5));
            return;
        } else if (playerTotal > 21) {
            System.out.println(name + " you are bust LOL, thank you for the $" + wager);
            return;
        }
        computerRunning = 2 + cards.nextInt(10);
        computerTotal += computerRunning;
        System.out.println(cname + " the dealers starting card is " + computerRunning);
        computerRunning = 2 + cards.nextInt(10);
        computerTotal += computerRunning;
        System.out.println(cname + " the dealers is keeping their second card hidden");
        if (computerTotal == 21) {
            System.out.println(computerTotal + " the house always wins haha, you lost your wager of $" + wager);
            return;

        } else if (computerTotal > 21) {
            System.out.println(computerTotal + "The house has busted with here is your money $" + (wager * 2));
            return;
        }
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(name + " do you want to continue? The dealer thinks you can continue. \n Y or N");
        String hit = input.nextLine();
        while (hit.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            playerRunning = 2 + cards.nextInt(10);
            playerTotal += playerRunning;
            System.out.println(name + " your new card is " + playerRunning);
            System.out.println(name + " your hand total is " + playerTotal);
            if (playerTotal == 21) {
                System.out.println("  \ni guess the house doesnt always win" + name + " well here is your money and sum $" + (wager * 2));
                return;
            } else if (playerTotal > 21) {
                System.out.println(name + " \nyou are bust LOL, thank you for the wager $" + wager);
                return;
            }
            if (computerTotal > 16) {
                System.out.println(cname + " the dealers is okay with their hand");
            } else {
                computerRunning = 2 + cards.nextInt(10);
                computerTotal += computerRunning;
                System.out.println(cname + " the dealers draws another card");
                if (computerTotal == 21) {
                    System.out.println(cname + " the dealer got " + computerTotal + " the house always wins haha, you lost your wager of $" + wager);
                    return;
                } else if (computerTotal > 21) {
                    System.out.println(computerTotal + " The house has busted, you got doulbe your wager $" + (wager * 2));
                    return;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(name + " do you want a hit? The dealer thinks you can continue. \n Y or N");
            hit = input.nextLine();
        }
        do {
            computerRunning = 2 + cards.nextInt(10);
            computerTotal += computerRunning;
            System.out.println(cname + " the dealers draws another card");
            if (computerTotal == 21) {
                System.out.println(cname + " the dealer got " + computerTotal + " the house always wins haha, you lost your wager of $" + wager);
                return;
            } else if (computerTotal > 21) {
                System.out.println(computerTotal + " The house has busted, you got doulbe your wager $" + (wager * 2));
                return;
            }
        } while (computerTotal < 16);
        if (playerTotal > computerTotal && playerTotal <= 21) {
            System.out.println(name + " i guess the house doesnt always win, here is your money $" + (wager * 2));
        } else if (computerTotal > playerTotal && computerTotal <= 21) {
            System.out.println("the house always wins haha, the dealer had " + computerTotal + " thank you for the money $" + wager);
        } else if (computerTotal == playerTotal && computerTotal <= 21 && playerTotal <= 21) {
            System.out.println("WE DRAWED??? sigh good  game i guess BUT house always wins so thank you for the $" + wager);
        } else if (computerTotal > 21 && playerTotal > 21) {
            System.out.println("and we both busted so no one wins");
        }
    }
;
``````
```````

This is just a piece of my game method that has my return function and as you can see it is a void with a return because I don't want to return anything I just want to go back to the main menu with no save really. the game works I don't know why this is a problem

Comment: Well, perhaps because you do the entire computer's hand first, without the player (that I can see).  That's not how blackjack is played.

Comment: i added the entire code so you can see now

Answer (score 0):

As commented above by markspace, the overall flow of this interpretation of Blackjack is flawed.

However, the main reason behind your return statements being incorrect may be that if the player and dealer both receive Blackjack (21) then it is either a push (money moves to next round) or you recieve your money back. You should never lose your money when getting a Blackjack.

See this link to view the flow of the game: https://www.practice-blackjack.com/blackjack-the-flow-of.html

Another reason may be that you need to push the wager and return the result into the function to add back to the total amount of money the player has.

Comment: I updated so you can see the entire thing, and I'm not trying to return anything as soon as someone wins, I want it to go to the main menu and have nothing returned so that they can start a fresh new game if they want.

Comment: Do you have function names or is this all procedural? Also as stated in my answer there's still the possibility your teacher is referring to the flow of the game which is incorrect. E.g. a tie results in the player losing their money where the player should keep their money.